# Transformer cooling difference between water cooling and air cooling

Tags: transformer, power-engineering, cooling, water, heat-protection

I just know air cooling method is cheaper than water cooling method. Please tell me what is the difference between air cooling and water cooling? And if you could please use some pictures to explain it.

Comment: Welcome. This question is not about electronic design and is a bit broad in scope. Normally we may post schematics, but not pictures. Also you are asking for elaboration on thermal dynamics and heat transfer, normally a full college course.

Comment: @Sparky256 Im sorry.Maybe i ask a wrong qustion.

Comment: Too many difficult questions LEO. For something so complex, single and specific questions have a better chance of being answered.

Comment: @Sparky256 Thank you for your advice.I will change my way when i ask question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For air the specific heat capacity Cv is about 0.72 kJ/kgK and water is about 4.18 kJ/kgK. This really means that per kg water moves more heat by a factor of just over 4.

This makes it a question of space on one hand as air cooling needs a large surface area and airflow either forced or natural.

Water cooling can take less space and have the possible advantage of part of the system can be remote but can require more parts to the system like pumps and control. Water has the disadvantage of conducting electricity...

Oil is also used to control transformer temperature and is basically as simple as a tank filled with oil with cooling tubes.

One part is also maintenance as the tubes need cleaning to stay efficient and I have spent many hours sanding and spraying oil cooled transformers..

A simple google search for “cooling transformers” gives: https://www.electricaleasy.com/2014/06/cooling-methods-of-transformer.html?m=1